# Cronjob output avoiding eval echo

Tags: bash, cron, echo, brace-expansion

I want to run a cronjob to commit and push some changes to a txt file. I created this small bash script,

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/git_key
number=$(eval "shuf -i 10-20 -n 1")
echo $number
for i in $(eval echo "{1..$number}")
        do
                echo "a" >> file.txt
                git commit -am "another add"
        done
git push
```

which runs perfectly fine if i run it as

```
./fakeGit.sh
```

But as soon as I put it into a cronjob (with crontab -e), like such:

```
48 17 * * * cd ~/GreenIsCool && ./fakeGit.sh > log.txt 2>&1
```

It only commit one time, and here is the output from log.txt

```
Agent pid 11687
Identity added: /home/----/.ssh/git_key (/home/----/.ssh/git_key)
18
[master 5dcc943] another add
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
To github.com:------.git
   4362432..5dcc943  master -> master
```

It feels like the loop is not working properly, I feel like it is because the echo may be redirected to the wrong place (because the cronjob is outputing to log.txt), but I cannot find a way to avoid this. How would I correct the script so it works with > log.txt ?

Comment: Add a shebang to your script. Cron's default shell is usually `sh` and not `bash`. `sh` does not know `{x..y}`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much ! For those also wondering, changing  ```eval echo "{1..$number}"``` to ```seq 1 $number``` also works, for the reason mentionned by Cyrus

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to replace `for i in $(eval echo "{1..$number}")` with `for((i=1; i<=4; i++))`.

Comment: And the eval on `shuf` is completely unnecessary; you want simply `number=$(shuf -i 10-20 -n 1)`

Comment: The `seq` fix gets rid of the Bash dependency so you can switch back to plain `sh` if you like with that.

Comment: Btw.; You can remove `1` from `seq 1 $number`.